# GlusterFS memory leak

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I am using glusterfs on Kubernetes for about 7GB of storage.   I have 4 nodes, two of which are holding the replica sets.  One of the nodes has a constant memory leak.  Starts out at about 100MB then slowly increases.  After 2 days it is 700MB.  Another 2 days and it will be 1.4GB.   Any suggestions on what is going on or how to diagnose it?

I am using version 4.0.3.

I have 26 split-brains that need fixed.  Could that be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of questions/problems are best handled on the [gluster-users mailinglist](https://lists.gluster.org/mailman/listinfo/gluster-users) ([archive](https://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/)). In your email, include a little more details, like the type of workload, number of bricks, number of volumes (maybe just `gluster volime info`), full name+arguments of the affected processes.